# How #define work? Strange result for CUBE(y) y*(y*y)

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#define CUBE(y)y*(y*y)
 main()
      {
        int j;
        j = CUBE(-2+4);
        printf("value of j = %d",j);
        getch();
      }
```

Output of this code is `-26`. I just want to know how this code give `-26` as an output. How `#define` work in this code. I know that `#define` permanent fix value for a variable or method but don't how this work for `CUBE` here. Can somebody please describe this step by step, means in easy way.

Comment: You know that a macro works by direct text substitution, right?  So perform the substitution manually, and think about what the result means...

Comment: This code is not compliant, conio.h is something outdated, non-standard and that you should not use, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conio.h

Comment: @kebs: I'd be willing to bet the OP is using a horribly ancient compiler, probably Turbo C++.

Comment: @duskwuff ya, I am using Turbo C++ for this code. Mostly I work on eclipse IDE for android. But today I am using Turbo C++ for describe C concepts to my sister. Then I found myself stuck with this `#define` thing.

Comment: many duplicates. e.g [Working of the C Preprocessor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6641818/working-of-the-c-preprocessor)

Comment: Please, please, don't try to learn C with such an ancient tool chain. Use a modern compiler, they are available for free, and read some documentation along with your trials. In particular if you are really an "android developper" as your user name suggests.

Comment: @JensGustedt Seconded. Turbo C++ is **over twenty years old**. C and C++ have changed considerably since it was released. By using it, you are teaching yourself bad habits, as well as locking yourself out of using any modern libraries.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It does:

```
j = -2 + 4 * (-2 + 4 * -2 + 4)
```

A more correct definition of CUBE would be

```
#define CUBE(y) ((y)*(y)*(y))
```

Comment: Yep, unless you have a very good reason for doing otherwise, *always* surround the substitution variable in a macro expansion with `()`.  And it's usually a good idea to surround the overall expansion with `()` as well.

Answer (score 5):

You should figure it out by yourself by using *`-E`* flag :

***`gcc test.c -E`***

```
# 1 "test.c"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "test.c"

 main()
      {
        int j;
        j = -2+4*(-2+4*-2+4); // <-- Check this substitution
        printf("value of j = %d",j);
        getch();
      }
```

To cube numbers you should be using `()` to change precedence and order of evaluation :-

`#define CUBE(y) (( y )*( y )*( y ))`

which will give after using *`-E`* flag :

`j = (( -2+4 )*( -2+4 )*( -2+4 ));`

Comment: this is a useful skill that all preprocessor abusers must learn!

Answer (score 3):

> I know that #define permanent fix value for a variable or method

You can't know that because it's **wrong**. The preprocessor works by *token replacement*. Whenever it sees the token sequence `CUBE(some tokens)` it replaces it with

```
  some tokens * ( some tokens * some tokens )
```

Now do the replacement of *some tokens* with `-2+4` yourself and do the math.

The preprocessor doesn't even know what a variable or object or method is. It operates purely in terms of *preprocessing tokens* (little chunks of characters; see the ISO C Standard for details).

Answer (score 2):

It expands as is :

```
-2+4*(-2+4*-2+4) = -2 +4(-6)= -26
```

To fix it surround y with ()

```
#define CUBE(y) ((y)*(y)*(y))
```

so you will get :

```
((-2+4) * (-2+4) * (-2+4))
```