# C preprocessor how it works

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

i have the following files

(its pseudo code, and i know the define, undef is ugly, but i would need it for some project)

if i compile those files and link them together - it seems to work - that in file3, file1 - `MYVAL == 1`

is it safe to assume this, that the preprocessor stuff is done file-by-file?

conf.h:

```
#define MYVAL 1
```

src1.c

```
#include "conf.h"
int maint(int argc, char ** argv) {
    printf("%d", MYVAL);
}
```

src2.c

```
#include "conf.h"
void demo() {
    #undef MYVAL
    #define MYVAL 2
    printf("%d", MYVAL);
}
```

src3.c

```
  #include "conf.h" 
  void demo2() {
       printf("%d", MYVAL);
  }
```

regards

Comment: The compiler doesn't actually see any "source" files, all it sees are [*translation units*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_%28programming%29). A translation unit is, roughly speaking, a source file and all included header files. The preprocessor reads a source file and all included header files, and generates a single file which is then fed to the compiler. Neither the preprocessor nor the compiler knows anything about other files.

Comment: As for the `#include` preprocessor directive, the preprocessor simply copy-paste the contents of the included file (after preprocessing) into the place where the `#include` directive was.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Working of the C Preprocessor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6641818/working-of-the-c-preprocessor)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Preprocessing is done per translation unit before the compilation phase (so way earlier than the linkage phase). In your case the preprocessor will expand that macro in each of your `.c` files individually based on your inclusion of the `conf.h` header file.

> is it safe to assume this, that the preprocessor stuff is done file-by-file?

Basically in your case yes. Each of your `.c` files is a distinct translation unit. (Unless they start including each other or something) They are preprocessed separately, compiled and then their objects get linked together.

Comment: It's an implementation detail, but notionally the preprocessor performs the `'#includes` #define macro substitutions and other preprocessor directives then starts compiling. However many implementations do something a little more incremental. You won't go far wrong if you imagine a big long temporary file is rolled out and then compiled.

Answer (score 1):

When you `#include "conf.h"` its code is placed *instead* of this line. This is the preprocessor's work. So, this `define` sentence is placed in each file.

*But* if you do `#define work(n) funcCall((n))` and `work(5);` then, it'll fail if `funcCall` is not defined in any of your files.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the preprocessor is used for each source file. It generates a preprocessed file from the source file and all include files that is actually passed to the C compiler.

When you `#define` something in a include file it gets in the preprocessed file. `#define`s in other source file doesn't care.